# Modern Relay - ConnectionConfig for multiple connections

Tags: relayjs

EDIT: after some research I found out that ReactRelayPaginationContainer does only support one `@connection` for now (relay release 1.0.0).

I am not sure how to deal with multiple Connections in a PaginationContainer using Relay Modern as the only examples I saw so far only included one Connection. To illustrate my concern, there is some code below where I am having troubles

```
export default createPaginationContainer(MyComponent,
{
    item: graphql`fragment mycomponent_item on Item {
        foos(first: $count_foo, after: $cursor_foo) @connection(key: item_foos) {
            pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
                endCursor
            }
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    ...foo_foo
                }
            }
        }
        bars(first: $count_bar, cursor: $cursor_bar) @connection(key: item_bars) {
            pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
                endCursor
            }
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    ...bar_bar
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }`
},
{
    direction: 'forward',
    getConnectionFromProps(props) {
        return props.item.foos && props.item.bars;
    },
    getFragmentVariables(prevVars, totalCount) {
        return {
            ...prevVars,
            count: totalCount,
        };
    },
    getVariables(props, {count, cursor}, fragmentVariables) {
        return {
            count,
            cursor,

        };
    },
    query: graphql`
        query itemPaginationQuery(
            $count_foo: Int!
            $cursor_foo: String
            $count_bar: Int!
            $cursor_bar: String
        ) {
            Item {
                ... mycomponent_item
            }
        }
    `
});
```

The problem is in the ConnectionConfig of [PaginationContainer](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/packages/react-relay/modern/ReactRelayPaginationContainer.js) of Relay Modern:

```
export type ConnectionConfig = {
 direction?: 'backward' | 'forward',
 getConnectionFromProps?: (props: Object) => ?ConnectionData,
 getFragmentVariables?: FragmentVariablesGetter,
 getVariables: (
   props: Object,
   paginationInfo: {count: number, cursor: ?string},
   fragmentVariables: Variables,
 ) => Variables,
 query: GraphQLTaggedNode,
};
```

It is clearly made just for one Connection in the PaginationContainer. And createPaginationContainer only accepts one of such ConnectionConfigs in it's constructor.

How am I supposed to deal with multiple Connections in one PaginationContainer?

Comment: I have a setup similar to yours in the old Relay and now that I'm switching to Relay Modern I'm also changing my code to have only one connection per container. Not the answer you're looking for but I think that it will be better to just create different containers and reuse a dumb component to render the data.

Comment: @hisa_py this is what I ended up doing eventually. Each fragment of pagination connection wraps one separate react component (some sort of list) anyway. So I am fine with this level of granularity.